# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I used the below query and getting an exception as below.

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2

Please help.

```
select s.ship_id from SHIP S where S.ship_id not in (SELECT ship_id FROM ship WHERE notes1 IS NOT NULL 
AND notes1 IN (select notes1 from ship WHERE SHIP_ID <> ? ))
AND S.SHIP_ID = ?
```

Comment: Add the code you use to call it.

Comment: You need to call it with two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This statement has two parameter references:

```
select s.ship_id
from SHIP 
where S.ship_id not in (SELECT ship_id
                        FROM ship
                        WHERE notes1 IS NOT NULL AND
                              notes1 IN (select notes1 from ship WHERE SHIP_ID <> ?
                                        )
                      ) and
      S.SHIP_ID = ?;
```

When you execute the query, you need to provide both of them, even though they are -- presumably -- the same.

You seem to what ships where the `notes1` field is unique for the ship.  You can do this in other ways:

```
select s.shipid
from (select s.*,
             min(shipid) over (partition by notes1) as mins,
             max(shipid) over (partition by notes1) as maxs
      from ships s
     ) s
where mins = maxs and shipid = ?;
```